# Is .NET DateTime buggy using ToString("U")?

Tags: .net, datetime

I have the next simple code...

```
Console.WriteLine(default(DateTime).Date.ToString("U"));
```

The, emitted text is (I have an spanish language installation):
"lunes, 01 de enero de 0001 3:00:00"

Why it starts at 3 hours, instead of 0? it is a bug?

Comment: Um, that's *not* `DateTime.Now`. Why don't you show us your *real* code?

Comment: What is the local time on your computer? `Now` includes hours/minutes/seconds, as should the `U` format specifier.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the code forgetting to put the Date property (which only gets the Date part, without time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well unless you've got a time machine or `DateTime` is *really* buggy, that's not the output of the code you posted, which uses `DateTime.Now`.

I suspect your code is *really* using `DateTime.MinValue` (or `new DateTime()`), and the reason that you're seeing 3am is that (as [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalFull)):

> The pattern is the same as the "F" pattern. However, the DateTime value is automatically converted to UTC before it is formatted.

So I suspect you're in a time zone where midnight on January 1st 0001 local time is 3am UTC. (`DateTimeZone.MinValue` has a "kind" of `Unspecified`, so will be treated as local when asked to convert to UTC. `DateTime` is a [bit of a mess](http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) around this area.)

Comment: Thanks Jon! My mistake: I wanted to say "DateTime.Now.Date", now fixed in the question. And yes!  I'm in an UTC - 4 location (one hour less by winter time adjust, I guess).

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA.: Even `DateTime.Now.Date` (which is more simply written as `DateTime.Today`) shouldn't be the 1st of January 0001. Anyway, glad it's all sorted now.

Comment: I plead guilty. The original value received was a DateTime default. Question corrected.